# OpenSSL NID for prime256v1 curve

Tags: openssl, ecdh

I am trying to create EC Diffie Hellman keys using OpenSSL. I am using the below line. I am trying to find the nid of prime256v1 curve but am not able to. I looked up in openssl documentation also. Does openssl not support prime256v1 curve?

`key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1); // prime256v1`

Comment: I would recommend using the example here. The nid is `NID_X9_62_prime256v1` https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman

Answer (score 3):

You can list all supported curves with the following command:

```
openssl ecparam -list_curves
```

Once you know whether the curve is supported, you can find the corresponding NID in *[openssl/include/openssl/obj_mac.h](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/4e6647506331fc3b3ef5b23e5dbe188279ddd575/include/openssl/obj_mac.h)* file.